# Nginx load balance with dedicated php-fpm server

Tags: linux, php, nginx, php-fpm

I got server setup with nginx+php-fpm and mysql. I have another server with only installed php-fpm, so wanted to use as load balance. But when I am using this dedicated server with php-fpm as load balancer, I got an error when opening page: "Access denied."

**/etc/nginx/nginx.conf**

```
user www-data;
worker_processes  3;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    tcp_nodelay        on;

    #gzip                on;

upstream php {
server dedicatedserverip:9000;
}

include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

**/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/site.org.conf**

```
server {
        listen   81;
        server_name site.org www.site.org;
        access_log  /var/log/nginx/site.org.log;
        error_log  /var/log/nginx/site.org.log;
root /home/www/site.org;
index  index.php;




   location ~ .php$ {
      fastcgi_pass php;
      fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    /home/www/$fastcgi_script_name;
        }


}
```

Why did I get this error? When I change only the fastcgi_pass to 127.0.0.1:9000 - all work fine.

Answer (score 2):

Find your php-fpm configuration (default source install location is /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.conf) and make sure that `listen.allowed_clients` is set to allow the IP of your Nginx box.

If this doesn't fix it then check your Nginx error log for further details.

Comment: Well, forgot to mention that, that's already done:
<value name="listen_address">9000</value>
   <valuename="allowed_clients">127.0.0.1,dedicatedip,nginxip</value>

There is nothing useful in logs.

Comment: I installed another php-fpm using ppa:brianmercer/php repository, I noticed that there is a little bit difference in php-fpm config style than this what i have used. Now after starting I got no errors, only blank page. Seems like php is not working via upstream. Tested with test webserver, php is running fine on localhost, but via upstream - he is showing blank page, like he don't process the php files.

Comment: Usually a blank page is a `nginx no input file specified` error that's just not displayed if there are no errors in the php logs. Are you sure the PHP files are located on the remote server in the path you pass in SCRIPT_FILENAME?

Comment: I am kinda shure, that it is the correct path, if change the `fastcgi_pass php` to `fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000` all works fine, but when using upstream - it's shows blank.

Comment: That's not what I mean. Your remote server needs the PHP files in the same directory as your local server. Are you sure that both servers have the files in the right directory?

Comment: Yes, I am sure! I spawned php5-cgi on 9000 port to test it, directory is right one, so its something with php-fpm!

Answer (score 0):

I recompiled all php.
If need some tutorial `http://docs.moodle.org/en/Development:Install_Moodle_On_Ubuntu_with_Nginx/PHP-fpm`