# File issue with NGinx & PHP-FPM on separate servers

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, network-share

I've done a bit of research on running NGinx and PHP with FastCGI on separate servers, and have successfully set it up on test virtual machines. I've ran into the problem that these articles describe...

- https://code.google.com/p/sna/wiki/NginxWithPHPFPM
- [Nginx load balance with dedicated php-fpm server](https://serverfault.com/questions/248209/nginx-load-balance-with-dedicated-php-fpm-server)

...which is that in order for this setup to work, the PHP files need to be in the same directory on BOTH servers, even though the machines running the php-fpm worker is actually executing the scripts. I've tested this myself; if I remove a file 'test.php' in the document root on the NGinx server, it throws a 404 or 403 even though the file still exists on the PHP-FPM machine.

My question: is there no way around this? I know using a central storage running NFS is one solution, but I would like to avoid the performance issues associated with that.

If it helps, here are my config files:

```
/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/test-app.conf

upstream test-app {
    server <php-fpm-server-ip>:9001;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name test.app.com;
    root /var/www/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        fastcgi_pass test-app;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

}
```

Comment: Would it be an option for you to install `nginx` on your machine running `php-fpm` as well?

Comment: Why aren't you colocating them? NGINX is very lightweight and doesn't usually consume too much RAM or CPU compared to PHP.

Comment: @JoelESalas and gf_: it's a high performance application

Comment: @ScottCrooks There's almost no way you've determined that NGINX is a performance bottleneck for you. I've done over a million NGINX events per hour and it has never been the bottleneck.

Comment: @JoelESalas You're right, NGinx is not really a "bottleneck." I guess I should have explained what I'm trying to accomplish. I want NGinx and PHP-FPM on separate servers so I can scale them independently. In other words, if I see that performance on the NGinx side is getting worse, I can add more servers for balancing.

Comment: What you could consider, is two Nginx instances - the front-end one directly interfaces with the public, handles your SSL, is fully 'hardened' to block any 'crazy' requests etc.  It proxies sanitized public requests to the back-end Nginx using straight HTTP.  This back-end interfaces with fastcgi, determines 404 etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to do this, remove this from nginx under your \.php location:

`try_files $uri $uri/ =404;`

That is what causes it to check the filesystem before passing the request off to the fcgi upstream. Also verify that the fcgi process has the root directory set properly so it can't read random php files now that nginx can't do existence checking.

Comment: ** UPDATE** @Andrew: Actually the fix you suggested doesn't work either. If I comment out that line, I get the same problem. Something I'm doing wrong? I only commented out the line from my code above, nothing else.

Comment: ** UPDATE 2 ** @Andrew: Actually that suggestions works, thank you!

Comment: This is not a good idea. You still have the potential to execute all requests bound for that location block as PHP code. If I upload a "JPG" that is really just PHP code, I can upload and execute my own code trivially on your site. There are many more examples.

Comment: In the presented config, it would only execute if the file ends in .php, and with or without try_files, PHP is still vulnerable to exactly the scenario you describe. Yes, there are plenty of security questions that need to be addressed. No, I'm not going to address them. Because of the way the question was phrased, the asker has to determine the security/performance tradeoffs for himself; I am merely pointing out the proximate cause of the error.

Answer (score 0):

**The php files need to exist on both 'nginx server' and 'php-fpm' server
Otherwise, nginx will return 404 page not found**

You need to sync all files from local nginx server (file must exist but can be 0 byte in content) and back-end php server (the actual php scripts)

Or you can share files between servers using SSHFS, NFS being another. You put the php script in the local folder (php-fpm server), then you mount this folder to nginx server. In the nginx.conf , document root you point it to the mounted folder 
That's it , no need to sync files